# How to erase a row like erasing an element in 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ vector and wanna ask a question about it. I built a 2D vector below:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and erase the 4 with these codes...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<vector<int>> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        vector<int> r;

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int input;
            cin >> input;
            r.push_back(input);
        }
        v.push_back(r);
    }
    v.at(1).erase(v.at(1).begin() + 0);//erase the 4
}
```

as we know the 5 replaced the 4 and became the 1st element in 2nd row, just like this...

```
1 2 3
5 6
7 8 9
```

But when i tried to erase or clear the whole 2nd row by...

```
v[1].clear();//or do v.at(1).erase(v.at(1).begin()+0) twice
```

the matrix became...

```
1 2 3

7 8 9
```

The elements in 2nd row were gone but the 3rd row didn't occupied it's place.
How should I erase(or clear)a whole row and make the next row to replace it's place?

Comment: Did you try `v.erase(v.begin() + 1);`?

Comment: `v[1].clear();` just did this: cleared the content on v[1], which now is a vector with o elements.
What you what to to is to erase (not clear) the element at index 1 of you "outer" array,
Just erase it as you did with the element of the inner vector

Comment: By the way...how to "clear" the v[1][0] element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clear` method only removes all elements from the vector but not the vector itself. You can achieve this with

```
v[1].clear();
v.erase(v.begin() + 1);
```

I will explain it in more detail: `v.begin()` returns an iterator pointing to the first element of the outer vector. `v.begin() + 1` advances this iterator by one pointing to the vector at `v[1]`. `v.erase(...)` takes this iterator and deletes the vector associated with it.

Please keep in mind to handle pointers correctly if they are allocated on the heap otherwise you would leak the used memory.

Comment: Thank you! dude, your answer really helps. By the way, how to clear the specific element like v[1][0]?

Comment: @LCh In this specific case `v[1].erase(v[1].begin() + 0);` should do the trick. It's basically the same but you're operating on a subvector. The `+ 0` can of course be deleted. A hint for the future: Take a look at the `<algorithm>` header it contains a lot of useful functions especially for containers like vector.